# QDockWidget with QPixmap - how to prevent QPixmap limiting the downsizing of parent widget while maintaining aspect ration?

Tags: qt, pyqt, resize, pyside, image-resizing

I haven't worked with images in labels for a long time so I'm stuck with an issue - once resized a `QPixmap` (loaded inside a `QLabel` or similar widget) cannot return to a smaller (downsized) version of itself. This is particularly annoying when working with docked widgets in a `QMainWindow` or similar setting:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

from random import seed
from random import random

class CentralWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        vb_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.label = QLabel('Central Widget')
        self.label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        vb_layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.setLayout(vb_layout)

class DockedWidget(QDockWidget):
    class Widget(QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
            QWidget.__init__(self)

            vb_layout = QVBoxLayout()

            self.label = QLabel()
            # Enable scaled contents, otherwise enjoy artifacts and visual glitches
            self.label.setScaledContents(True)
            self.rimg = QImage(self.width(),self.height(), QImage.Format_Grayscale8)
            self.rimg.fill(Qt.black)
            print(self.rimg.width(), self.rimg.height())
            for j in range(self.height()):
                for i in range(self.width()):
                    r = round(random()* 255)
                    if r % 2 == 0:
                        self.rimg.setPixel(i, j, qRgb(255, 0, 0))
            self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.rimg))
            vb_layout.addWidget(self.label)

            self.setLayout(vb_layout)
        
        def resizeEvent(self, e: QResizeEvent) -> None:
            super().resizeEvent(e)

            preview = self.label.pixmap()
            # FIXME Trying to figure out a way to scale image inside label up and down
            self.label.setPixmap(preview.scaled(self.label.width(),self.label.height(),Qt.KeepAspectRatio))

    def __init__(self):
        QDockWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Docked Widget')
        
        self.widget = DockedWidget.Widget()
        self.setWidget(self.widget)        


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(300, 100, 270, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')

        dockedwidget = DockedWidget()
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, dockedwidget)

        widget = CentralWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)


seed(1)
app = QApplication([])
win = MyWindow()
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

I've tried to link the pixmap's scaling to the parent label, which in terms should be controlled by the behaviour of the docked widget. Initially I was facing the issue that the image would stretch and create weird artifacts:

[image: Resizing using override of resizeEvent]

I figured out I had to enable scaled contents (`QLabel.setScaledContents()`) but I'm still facing the issue that I cannot go below the initial size of the image:

**Minimum size restricts resizing beyond the initially set image size**
[image: Downsizing cannot go further then the initially set size of the image]

**Increasing the size is not a problem**
[image: Increasing the size is working]

I need to make the image capable of downsizing properly, otherwise it compromises the rest of the components in the layout in my actual setup. I'm thinking that the solution lies somewhere between the resize event and the size policy.

Answer (score 0):

QLabel does not provide support for aspect ratio, and it normally only allows to scale it to sizes *bigger* than the image size (but this can be worked around using `setMinimumSize(1, 1)`).

While you could create a subclass that actually paints the proper aspect ratio no matter of the widget size, it's often not necessary, as you could use a QGraphicsView and a basic pixmap item.

```py
class ImageWidget(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFrameShape(0)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            QGraphicsView {
                background: transparent;
            }
        ''')

        rimg = QImage(640, 480, QImage.Format_Grayscale8)
        rimg.fill(Qt.black)
        for j in range(480):
            for i in range(640):
                r = round(random()* 255)
                if r % 2 == 0:
                    rimg.setPixel(i, j, qRgb(255, 0, 0))

        scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(scene)
        self.pixmapItem = scene.addPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(rimg))

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.fitInView(self.pixmapItem, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)


class DockedWidget(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QDockWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Docked Widget')
        
        self.widget = ImageWidget()
        self.setWidget(self.widget)
```

<sup>Note: 1. use nested classes only when actually necessary, otherwise they only make the code cumbersome and difficult to read; 2. all widgets have a default size when created (640x480, or 100x30 for widgets created with a parent), so using `self.width()` and `self.height()` is pointless.</sup>